# SQL-like групповые операции в Python

Tags: sql, python

Есть набор данных, примерно такого содержания:

```
[
    TopServicesDetailedResult(
        region_id=69021624L, 
        month=datetime.datetime(2014, 5, 1, 0, 0), 
        agency_id=1586344917L, 
        loc_id=69023858)
    TopServicesDetailedResult(
        region_id=69021624L, 
        month=datetime.datetime(2014, 5, 1, 0, 0), 
        agency_id=1586344917L, 
        loc_id=5000411755)
    TopServicesDetailedResult(
        region_id=1232535L, 
        month=datetime.datetime(2014, 5, 1, 0, 0), 
        agency_id=6521L, 
        loc_id=472050)
    TopServicesDetailedResult(
        region_id=1232535L,  
        month=datetime.datetime(2014, 5, 1, 0, 0), 
        agency_id=6521L, 
        loc_id=472056)
]
```

Как средствами Python правильно сделать что-то вроде вот такого:

```
select region_id,
       month,
       agency_id,
       count(*)
from some_table
group by region_id,
         month,
         agency_id
```

т.е. говоря обычным языком мне нужна группировка элементов скписка по составному ключу. Что-то мне подсказывает, что это можно сделать при помощи `functools`, но нужен пинок в правильном направлении.

PS: нужно постараться это сделать без применения numPy, Pandas, Matplotlib и прочих доп. библиотек, т.к. это лишние зависимости, которым никто не обрадуется в условиях продакшена.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby

Comment: Спасибо, то, что доктор прописал. Не без плясок с бубном, конечно, но все же)

Comment: Перенесите, пожалуйста, необходимую информацию с сайта в ответ. Это сделает его гораздо более ценным, особенно для людей, которые не знают английский.